# Hang Pendant light with loop

Tags: light

I want to update the lights in my kitchen with pendant lights.  [image]

However, for one light, the current light has a loop over to a hook to hang the light in the appropriate spot.  Like this....
[image]

I want to use the current holes in the ceiling for this - but how do I - can I loop/move this over to hang in the appropriate spot?  How do I support/hang the light from the desired location?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you ok with having a blank cover over the current electric box and installing a new box in the desired location?

Comment: you could cut the cord on the old one after the hook and tie it into the new one's wires, after you cut off it's base part; a mashup.

Comment: Sure would be a lot easier if you weren't set on buying new lamps that have down rods instead of just a cable.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I support/hang the light from the desired location?

The new lights will mount to the boxes that are under the pendent light box covers. You can remove the hook eye and patch the hole.

Moving a light over 8 inches will make almost no difference in the light pattern.

It appears the original light needed some support besides the box so they install the hook and loop.

Good Luck!

Comment: 8 inches may not make a difference in the light pattern, but if it is over a table it will make the difference between center-of-the-table and guests-banging-their-heads-on-every-time

Comment: I would agree with the center of the table part. If 8" off center means you are now banging your head you have a pretty small table there.